# SwipeRefreshlLayout Android behaviour

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

I'm developing an app. At some point, the user can refresh the layout so I decided to use the SwipeRefreshLayout class since its both more practical and more elegant. Everything is working great but I wonder about 1 thing.

I don't seem to be able to find a way to make the view scroll down while the refresh animation is active. You can see what I mean on pic below:

[image: this]

I know the picture is about Kitkat and generally is about 2 years old with old google libraries and I wonder if Google changed the way Android handles the animation? I tried like 4-5 different apps from Google Play and they all show the same behaviour. I've tried it on Jelly Bean and Lollipop using the emulator as well as on Marshmallow using my actual device.

Comment: Version 21 of support library replaces old style with circle.  so use support library below 21 you will get that :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was as I suspected then :). The thing is that lowering the support library revision is really messy and also severely breaks my app by disabling the appcompatactivity as well as removing the themes and messing with every xml in the project. Creating a new project based on the older APIs could be a solution but is not worth my time and effort since I have to change a lot of code. Anyway thanks for your answer. You can create an answer so I can upvote it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 21 of support library replaces old style with circle. so use support library below 21 you will get that :)
here is in this [link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/) please go through Ankit Saliya comment u can check that screen shot with full description that how will do that